# Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, calculus, constrained-dynamics

[image]

In this Lagrangian (from the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0192 - page 4), $\eta, \mu, \nu, \& \lambda$ are lagrange multipliers.

My question is:  why do they include $\nu$ and $\lambda$ inside the integral but the others not? In other words, when do we use varying lagrange multipliers?

In the same paper they use this theorem of calculus of variation:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L'}(X_e)(\bar{X}) = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}L(X_e + \epsilon \bar{X})|_{\epsilon=0} = 0
\end{equation}

What is $\bar{X}$? What do this theorem differ from differentiation?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE. Please do not use photos to display formulas and use MathJax instead.(Just like you do in your second equation.) Also try to ask only one question within a single post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the mulipliers  are inside the integral because they wish to enforce $x'=\cos \theta$ at all points $s$. To do this they  need a separate  Lagrange multiplier $\nu(s)$ at each point $s$.

If they wrote $\nu\int_0^D (x'-\cos \theta) ds$, with  only one $\nu$,  they  would only get $\int_0^D x' ds= \int_0^D \cos\theta ds$, which is not at all the same thing.

Look at problem 3 in [this](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys508/fa2020/508hw3.pdf) homework set for an example.  In that problem the lagrenace multiplier for point with coordinate $s$ is the tension in the cable at that point.